# Thymeleaf: validation error by field

Tags: spring, forms, validation, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf + Spring and form validation, I want to display errors that are related to a field next to this field.

```
<input type="text"
  th:field="*{companyName}" class="form-control"
  placeholder="Code client" th:errorClass="'error'"/>
```

If the field has an error, the class "error" is applied indeed. But is there an easy way to display also the validation error of the field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code to display error:

```
<p class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('companyName')}" th:errors="*{companyName}"></p>
```