# th:field prevents inputs from being displayed in result .html page

Tags: html, spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I was trying to display validation errors using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510520/thymeleaf-validation-error-by-field) but it doesn't work. 
Here is my user registration form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${newUser}"  method="post">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{username}">
  <input type="password" th:field="*{password}">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

If i use name="username" and name="password" instead of th:field it binds the object just fine.

Here is my controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
public String handlePostRequest (@Valid @ModelAttribute("newUser") UserModel newUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println(bindingResult.getFieldErrorCount());
        for (FieldError err:bindingResult.getFieldErrors()){
            System.out.println(err.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }else{
        newUser.setRoles("USER");
        userRepository.addUser(newUser);
        return "redirect/:login";
    }
    return "register";
}
```

I worked around it by passing error message as a model attribute instead of using #fields.hasErrors

```
@Controller
 public class RegisterController {

    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public RegisterController(IUserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping({"/register"})
    public String handleGetRequest (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("errorHappened",false);
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String handlePostRequest (@Valid @ModelAttribute("newUser") UserModel newUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("errorHappened",true);
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("errorHappened",false);
            newUser.setRoles("USER");
            if(userRepository.addUser(newUser))
                return "redirect:/login";
            else{
                model.addAttribute("errorHappened",true);
                String usernameTaken = "Username is already taken";
                model.addAttribute("errorMsg", usernameTaken);
                return "register";
            }
        }
        return "register";
    }

}
```

and then i display error like this

```
<span class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${errorHappened}" th:text="${errorMsg}" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
```

Comment: Provide your `GetMapping` too. without your full code (related) we can not help you

Comment: What do you mean "prevents inputs from being displayed"? Is there an exception in the template processing? Do they not appear? Give us details.

Comment: @Jorge.V form element does not appear in generated html